# Python Django Syntax error

Tags: python, django, bash, shell

I am New to python and I am learning Django right now by following online tutorials 
I installed python and check by getversion command in python shell
so, I started to work on the First project, The problem in this project I am facing is when I run the command in command prompt it gives the output but in python shell it's not working it's giving syntax error, Here below I mentioned the command and error I am facing in my first app, Please review it and guide me
I typed the following command in Shell and Prompt of Python 
django admin startproject mysite

It gives the following Error
Invalid Syntax

Before executing this I run this in command prompt, by cd: comment I changed my directory, for example, i changed my directory to desktop and give the command " django admin startproject mysite"
 and execute the command and view the result in localhost

My issue is why it's not getting in python shell

Answer (score 0):

From the command line, cd into a directory where you’d like to store your code, then run the following command:

```
$ django-admin startproject mysite
```

This will create a mysite directory in your current directory.

The command would have created a folder structure like the following in your current directory.

```
mysite/
    manage.py
    mysite/
        __init__.py
        settings.py
        urls.py
        wsgi.py
```